# How to solve Error:1067?

Tags: mysql

What I was trying to do is to tune my MySql server. Because, I need to read and load data from huge (more than 1GB) csv file. I change some lines in my.ini file. Firstly it works fine. But after I shutdown the machine next time mysql server is not opening and giving an error, 
i.e. Error:1067 the process terminated unexpectedly in your machine..

I changed some lines like-

```
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

innodb_buffer_pool_size=2G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=20M

innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_log_buffer_size=8M

innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1

innodb_purge_threads=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
```

Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

This error message appears if the Windows service launcher has quit immediately after being started.

This problem usually happens because the license key has not been correctly deployed(license.txt file in the license folder). More details about this can found [here.](http://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/ug-editor/tasks/floating-license-server-setup.html)